# How can I manually calculate the type of functions with class constraints?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

The following typing rule for function application

```
    f :: A -> B
    e :: A
    -----------
    f e :: B
```

doesn't take into account an `f` with *class constraints*. How can I manually calculate the type of, for example:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
3 :: Int
---------------------------
(+) 3 :: ?
```

Comment: `Num Int => Int -> Int`, and since `Num Int` holds, you can eliminate that so, `Int -> Int`.

Comment: Thank you, @WillemVanOnsem. What's `Num Int` ?

Comment: a constraint. A constraint that is satisfied if `Int` is a "*member*" of the `Num` typeclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For:

```
(+) :: Num a =>  a -> a -> a
3   ::          Int
```

We know that `a` (the first parameter) is the same type as `Int` (the type of `3`), so that means that `a ~ Int` (`a` and `Int` are the same type), so that means that:

```
(+)   :: Num a =>  a ->  a  ->  a
3     ::          Int
------------------------------------
(+) 3 :: Num Int =>     Int -> Int
```

Since `Int` is a member of the `Num` typeclass, we can remove `Num Int =>`, and thus obtain:

```
(+)   :: Num a =>  a ->  a  ->  a
3     ::          Int
------------------------------------
(+) 3 ::                Int -> Int
```